# Cell disabling through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Following script was written to restrict access to some fields based on values of another column within an application. Currently the script does not allow the user to type any value and prompts the correct error message. However users are still able to drag and drop values to the cell, there is no error shown and is allow to go through with the transaction.

Any suggestion to disable the cell so users cant type or drag drop values?

```
public function OnKeyDown(sender: Object , e : KeyEventArgs)
{
    if(source == "")
    {
        var WHSLColumn = listControl.GetColumnIndexByName('WHSL'); 

        var location =listControl.ListView.SelectedItems[0][WHSLColumn];


        if(location.Equals("01XXXXX") || location.Equals("02YYYYYY")  
        || location.Equals("03T1-ZZZZZ") || location.Equals("WOISABA")
        )
        {
            ConfirmDialog.ShowInformationDialog("Unable to Allocate Quantity From Location: " + location); 
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try disabling drag and drop on the page:

```
<BODY ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
```

Comment: This is one solution, yes. Preferably we are trying to limit the functionality for the mentioned criteria only (4 locations), and not the entire page.

Comment: Then you could apply those two event handlers to your four locations instead (: